# Android / (simple) JSON: How to use String value for JSONObject.get()

Tags: android, json

I know this might be a newbie Question, but I didn't find a solution.
I'm trying to use the value of a String variable for JSONObject.get.
I have to use this for a request to Google Books, the value is OK, but it is not accepted for the call inside .get().
I get a NullPointerException.

Here's the code snippet:

```
 public static String getImageLink(JSONObject book)
     {
         JSONObject volumeInfo = (JSONObject)book.get("volumeInfo");
         JSONObject imageLinks = (JSONObject) volumeInfo.get("imageLinks");
         if (imageLinks.get("thumbnail")!=null)
         {

             String thumbnail = imageLinks.get("thumbnail").toString();
             Log.i(TAG,"LINK1:" + thumbnail);
             return thumbnail;
         }else{
             Set<String> keys = imageLinks.keySet();
             String[] nails = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
             String nail = ('"'+ nails[0]+'"');
             String thumbnail = imageLinks.get ( nail ).toString();

             Log.i(TAG,"LINK2:" + nails[0].toString());
             return thumbnail;
         }
     }
```

The error seems to be here: `String thumbnail = imageLinks.get ( nail ).toString();`

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
And here's the error Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.googlebooks, PID: 32387
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.googlebooks.GoogleBooksHelper.getImageLink(GoogleBooksHelper.java:106)
at com.example.googlebooks.TableActivity$BookListDownloadTask.onPostExecute(TableActivity.java:108)
at com.example.googlebooks.TableActivity$BookListDownloadTask.onPostExecute(TableActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I use the JSON-response for a direct call, everything works.
I get the right Objects/Strings (thumbnail, smallThumbnail, ..)for calling the links.
Just the String variable inside the .get-call isn't accepted.

Comment: post your json rsponse

Comment: Post the crash logcat output.

Comment: Logs and JSON.response added.

Comment: json response mean what is being passed to the method ?? post that string..!! Something like : `{"Success":"1","Result":[{}]}`. **I suppose your `book` object is NULL**.

Comment: the book object is not null, if I use the value of the variable directly, it works.It does not work, if I use the variable.So "thumbnail" works, but the using the variable that holds the value "thumbnail" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing is depends on your JsonObject (book) structure, but for getting any string value form any json object you have to use jsonObject.getString("your_key"). it will return your string value.

Comment: I'm aware of parsing and the structure also, If I use the key directly ("thumbnail"), it works, but if I use the variable holding the key ("thumbnail") it doesn't work.

Comment: So make the variable public static final String THUMBNIL= "thumbnail";